# How to change text based upon select id and radio name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am bit lost over here.
I am trying to change the content of the id #total to "not eligible", if the user selects option in "countries" where the "data-class" is "false" and selects the radio "value" to "business". So if select is False and radio is business then change the #total to not eligible.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.countries').change(function() {
    var self = $(this).find('option:selected')
    $('input:radio[name="service"]').change(
      function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Business' && self.attr("data-class") == 'False') {
          return $('#total').text('Not Eligible')
        }
      }
    ).change()
  }).change()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control countries">
  <option value="AUSTRALIA" data-class="False" data-tx_1="63">AUSTRALIA</option>
  <option value="USA" data-class="True" data-tx_1="65">USA</option>
  <option value="GERMANY" data-class="True" data-tx_1="69">GERMANY</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label for="id_service_0"><input type="radio" name="service" value="Economy" required id="id_service_0" />Economy</label>
<label for="id_service_1"><input type="radio" name="service" value="Business" required id="id_service_1" />Business</label>
<label for="id_service_2"><input type="radio" name="service" value="First" required id="id_service_2" />First</label>

<p>Total Price is <span id="total"></span></p>
```

Comment: Don't define your radio _change_ handler inside the `<select>` _change_ handler. Every time the latter changes, you will be adding a new event handler to the former

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have 2 separate change event
2. Check for value and compare

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.countries').change(function() {
    var self = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var inputvalue = $('input:radio[name="service"]:checked').val();
    if (inputvalue == 'Business' && self.attr("data-class") == 'False') {
      $('#total').text('Not Eligible')
    } else {
      $('#total').text('Eligible')
    }
  }).change()
  $('input:radio[name="service"]').change(function() {
    var self = $('.countries').find('option:selected');
    var inputvalue = $('input:radio[name="service"]:checked').val();
    if (inputvalue == 'Business' && self.attr("data-class") == 'False') {
      $('#total').text('Not Eligible')
    } else {
      $('#total').text('Eligible')
    }
  }).change()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control countries">
  <option value="AUSTRALIA" data-class="False" data-tx_1="63">AUSTRALIA</option>
  <option value="USA" data-class="True" data-tx_1="65">USA</option>
  <option value="GERMANY" data-class="True" data-tx_1="69">GERMANY</option>
</select>

<input type="radio" name="service" value="Economy" required id="id_service_0" />Economy
<input type="radio" name="service" value="Business" required id="id_service_1" />Business
<input type="radio" name="service" value="First" required id="id_service_2" />First

<p>Total Price is <span id="total"></span></p>
```

Comment: This leads to unnecessary code duplication because both event handlers are nearly identical.

Comment: @cfillion nearly but not identical

Comment: @guradio It could easily be merged into a single handler applied to both elements with no duplication at all.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your code is indeed working. The reason you thinks it is not might be that you're not resetting the label text. See my snippet below. I've just added an "else" condition to your inner if statement.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.countries').change(function() {
    var self = $(this).find('option:selected')
    $('input:radio[name="service"]').change(
      function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Business' && self.attr("data-class") == 'False') {
          $('#total').text('Not Eligible')
        }
        else{
          $('#total').text('Eligible')
        }
      }
    ).change()
  }).change()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control countries">
  <option value="AUSTRALIA" data-class="False" data-tx_1="63">AUSTRALIA</option>
  <option value="USA" data-class="True" data-tx_1="65">USA</option>
  <option value="GERMANY" data-class="True" data-tx_1="69">GERMANY</option>
</select>

<input type="radio" name="service" value="Economy" required id="id_service_0" />
<input type="radio" name="service" value="Business" required id="id_service_1" />
<input type="radio" name="service" value="First" required id="id_service_2" />

<p>Total Price is <span id="total"></span></p>
```

Comment: If user selects radio option first and then the countries, the #total id is not changing. So i guess the correct approach is having two separate change events. But thank you so much for your answer